# Assign a value to a variable in a select statement and then used to find value in nested select statement

Tags: sql

I'm getting the error

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Here's my SELECT statement.

```
SELECT A.vendor_id, **@vendor_employee** = A.vendor_employee_id
    , B.txt_first_name, B.txt_last_name,
    SELECT txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Element, 
        (CASE 
            WHEN txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value <> '' 
                AND txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value IS NOT NULL 
            THEN txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value 
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Date) 
        END) AS Vendor_Detail_Element_Value 
    FROM t_vendor_employee_detail 
    WHERE vendor_employee_id = **@vendor_employee**)

FROM...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, basically you can't return data and assign variables in the same select statement. What I think you intend to do is a `correlated subquery` which references an outer value.

That wolud look something like this:

```
SELECT A.vendor_id, A.vendor_employee_id
    , B.txt_first_name, B.txt_last_name,
    (SELECT d.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Element
    FROM t_vendor_employee_detail d
    WHERE d.vendor_employee_id = A.Vendor_employee_id /* references outside the subqquery */)

FROM...
```

but you are also returning multiple rows in your subquery which should probably be rewritten as a join.

```
SELECT A.vendor_id, A.vendor_employee_id
    , B.txt_first_name, B.txt_last_name,
    d.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Element, 
        (CASE 
            WHEN D.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value <> '' 
                AND d.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value IS NOT NULL 
            THEN d.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value 
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, d.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Date) 
        END) AS Vendor_Detail_Element_Value 
FROM vendor_table_A A 
    INNER JOIN t_vendor_employee_detail d
         ON d.vendor_employee_id = A.vendor_employee_id
    INNER JOIN vendor_table_B B 
         ON...
```

These examples will give you the basic idea but we would really need the whole query to give you a complete solution.

Comment: This fixed the problem.  I didn't think I could use an outer value in the nested query. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something that could be rewritten using a JOIN.  It's hard to say how without seeing the whole query, but here is an attempt:

```
SELECT A.vendor_id, A.vendor_employee_id
    , B.txt_first_name, B.txt_last_name,
    c.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Element, 
        (CASE 
            WHEN c.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value <> '' 
                AND c.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value IS NOT NULL 
            THEN c.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Value 
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, c.txt_Vendor_Employee_Detail_Date) 
        END) AS Vendor_Detail_Element_Value 
FROM ...

INNER JOIN t_vendor_employee_detail c
ON c.vendor_employee_id = A.vendor_employee_id
```

As the error message says, you cannot use a variable in the way you are trying.

Comment: Ya, I did use that join.  My problem was that I didn't know I could it would recognize the outer value in the nested query.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve and assign data altogether using a merge statement.

Something like this:
    DECLARE @ID TABLE (
        ID INT
    )

```
MERGE INTO @ID
USING (
    select 1 a,2 b,3 c
) as src
ON ( 1 = 2 )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID)
VALUES (Src.a)
OUTPUT src.b, src.c
;

SELECT * FROM @ID
```